# playframework 2.4.2 ebean integration

Tags: java, mysql, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am trying to discover play! but got stuck at my first steps: configuring ebean. [**Compilation error: package com.avaje.ebean does not exist**]

Setup :

- playframework 2.4.2 (latest at the time of writing), ebean
- intellij idea, mySQL

I have followed all the instructions from: [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24) and [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaEbean). I created a simple User class, annotated @Entity and extending com.avaje.ebean.Model. The IDE suggested importing class Model from either avaje or play, but the compiler throws the abovementioned error.

I got pretty much stuck here :(

***build.sbt***

```
name := """randomApi"""
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.21"
)
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

and ***plugins.sbt***

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.2")

//addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
//addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0") 
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

&&& addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0") &&&
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define which ebean class in the application.conf like below?

```
ebean.default = ["models.User"]
```

assuming your User class is under models package.

add below line in your plugins.sbt file without '&'

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

Just to make sure, you could try reload the app and update the dependencies

```
[~] $ reload
[~] $ update
```